# solving system of equations $(x,y,z)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

given: $xyz=64, xz=16, yz=32$.

($x,y,z$ are real numbers)

Need to find $(x,y,z)$.

**MY TRY**: dividing $\frac{xyz}{xz}=\frac{64}{16}$ so $y=4$ and so on..

Is there any other way to solve this system?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could substitute for $x$ and $y$ in $xyz=64$ seeing that $x=\frac{16}{z}$ and $y=\frac{32}{z}$ resulting in $\frac{16}{z}\frac{32}{z}z=64$  Solving for $z$ gives $z=8$.

Comment: thank's not that short but it will work too.